# Is there a way to add zone_weights() in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

I successfully managed to use `field_weights` in `Sphinx` to get the relevance I needed. However my fields are actually inclusive of several `html tags` (e.g. `<Author>` and `<Description>`). I need those in one field because of some other config work I am doing. So the `field_weights` won't in fact work for me. What I need is a way to weight the `ZONES` I set up in sphinx. However `zone_weights` is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well no, there are no explicit zone weights.

Can perhaps use the individual boost modifier to boost words, that are also within the zone...

```
ZONE:(h3) banada^1.234
```

Comment: Thanks, that would never work, the list is sort of infinite. Sort of stuck here; I need the zones in each of the fields but need the field_weights.

Comment: Is there a way to make an index FROM another index? In other words once I do the work I want on the field with all the html tags/zones and store that indexed data can I now make another index with just one of the zones?